# Gravar Caminho do FileUpload dentro de um UpdatePanel ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, file-upload

Caros,

A pergunta da minha dúvida é bem simples. Como faço para gravar o caminho do meu arquivo do FileUpload em algum controle ou ViewState, com esse FileUpload estando dentro de um UpdatePanel?

Na verdade estou usando o controle AJAX do AsyncFileUpload, já que um simples FileUpload não funciona com Post Back parcial. Quanto a isso sem problemas. Então, eu gravo o arquivo selecionado na página no meu servidor, porém ao mesmo tempo que eu gravo eu preciso usar esse mesmo caminho (full path) para usar ele depois, em um evento de um botão. Já tentei usar ViewState, já tentei alterar algumas propriedades do UpdatePanel, já tentei encontrar uma forma de fazer isso com JavaScript, mas nenhum desses recursos surtiu efeito.

Alguém saberia me dizer como poderia resolver esse problema?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda de todos.

Abraços!

Comment: Caso tenho solucionado o seu problema, marcar como resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de buscas e buscas, finalmente eu consegui encontrar a única solução. Na verdade é até simples. Adicionei um controle do tipo hidden (HiddenField) na página para gravar a informação que eu quero. Tem um evento do AsyncFileUpload chamado `OnUploadedComplete`, onde trabalhando dentro desse evento bastou eu adicionar um `ScriptManager` para gravar o valor da variável que eu queria nesse controle hidden que coloquei na página, simples assim. Agora eu posso trabalhar dessa maneira que eu quero, e sinceramente me parece a única maneira de se fazer isso. De qualquer forma, se alguém souber outra maneira de fazer, por favor deixem seu comentário, sempre é bem vindo.

Este seria o script:

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "path", "top.$get('" + hfCaminhoArquivo.ClientID + "').value = '" + filePath + "';", true);`

[Aqui](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/blob/master/AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx.cs) foi onde encontrei a resposta:

Answer (score 0):

Com panel também não consegui, e usando hiddenfield aqui deu certo!
Veja se o exemplo é útil. No final vai ficar o nome e a extensão:

```
string fileName;
 if (fuArquivo01.HasFile)
 {
  fileName = null;
  fileName = fuArquivo01.FileName;
  fileName += System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fuArquivo01.FileName).ToLower();
  HiddenField1.value = fileName;
 }
```

Comment: Caso tenho solucionado o seu problema, marcar como resposta.